# Find highest value in a column matching given statement increase by 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write an SQL query that finds a value in a column and increases it by one. For example:

```
 id | reply                          | comment_parent_id | order_by 
----+--------------------------------+-------------------+----------
  1 | Hello World I am a reply       |                 1 |        1 
  2 | Hello World I am a reply also  |                 1 |        2 
  3 | Hello World I am a reply also  |                 1 |        3 
  5 | Hello World I am a reply also  |                 2 |        1
```

The above is an example of my table. When I insert a new row and the `comment_parent_id = 1` then that row being inserted the `order_by` field needs to be 4. So if I inserted another new row and the `comment_parent_id = 2` then the `order_by` field needs to equal 2. I hope I explained my self clear enough. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (reply, comment_parent_id, order_by)
SELECT @new_reply, @new_parent_id, IFNULL(MAX(order_by)+1, 1)
FROM table
WHERE comment_parent_id = @new_parent_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a nested `SELECT` in your `INSERT` -

```
INSERT INTO test
     SELECT NULL, 
            'Hello World I am a reply also', 
            ?, 
            count(comment_parent_id)+1 
     FROM test 
     WHERE comment_parent_id = ?;
```

The `?`'s represent the `comment_parent_id` that you are inserting.

see this SQLFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d230f/1

Comment: This assumes no gaps in the `order_by` sequence.